# How do I open a dotx file with Excel Macro

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I want to use this Word template to open a new Document

However my code opens the file in "Edit Mode"

```
Dim Paragraphe As Object, WordApp As Object, WordDoc As Object
File = "C:\Source\File.dotx"
'Word session creation
Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
'word will be closed while running
WordApp.Visible = True
'open the .doc file
Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open(File)
```

Comment: For Word, templates are used to add documents, not opened. Here is the Microsoft support page on the Documents.Add method: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.documents.add  Here is my page on how templates work in Word. http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/templates.htm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will want to use the `.Add` method instead of `.Open` and specify the `Template` argument.

```
Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Add(Template:=File)
```

Keep in mind this new document will not have a filename when it is created.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.documents.add